# Как отловить окончание процесса в отдельной задаче

Tags: android, java

Процесс запроса данных с сервера реализован в отдельной задаче

```
 {new DownloadPageTask().execute(data_url);}
```

Как указать приложению, чтобы оно остановилось, пока этот процесс не вернет результат?

Получаю результат таким способом:

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ResString = result ;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, result );
    }
```

Comment: Что значит "приложение остановилось"? Что вы под этим подразумеваете?

Comment: thread#join()

Comment: согласен, что выражение "приложение остановилось" некорректно.
Имел ввиду следующее: чтобы после строки

     {new DownloadPageTask().execute(data_url);}

следующую строку не выполняло, пока не вернется некая переменная ResString (код выше).
т.е.

          {new DownloadPageTask().execute(data_url);}
          String sss = RegString;

Comment: Ответ "thread#join()" пока не знаю как применить. У меня нет явного потока, а есть {new DownloadPageTask().execute(data_url);}.
Я пока плохо разбираюсь в потоках.

Comment: UI поток нельзя тормозить, иначе пользователь будет думать что у вас глючное приложение и сразу удалит. Пользуйтесь колбэками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все очень просто - разделите ваш метод на два.  
В первом делайте все, до вызова {new DownloadPageTask().execute(data_url);} включительно.  
Во втором - все что после этого (что нужно выполнить после выполнения асинк таски).  
Второй метод вызываете в onPostExecute.

И на время выполнения этой асинк таски неплохо бы показать пользователю, что приложение занято, что бы он не тыкал все подряд.

Comment: Да, можно так сделать, но я хотел реализовать в виде отдельного класса, к нему обращаться и получать ответ.

Comment: ну так передавайте ему ссылку на активити, например в конструкторе, и вызывайте в onPostExecute что-то вроде myActivity.taskFinished(results);

Comment: А почему не получается вот так:

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ResGet = true;
            ResString = result ;}
а в методе, который вызвал {new DownloadPageTask().execute(data_url);}
прописываю следующее и жду, когда ResGet станет true;

            while (!ResGet){
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            cnt++;
        }
Как только поменялось значение ResGet иду дальше, но оно не меняется, хотя PostExecute выполнился.

Comment: @kaaa    
1) каждый потк в Java имеет свою собственную копию переменной, и изменяя ее в одном потоке совершенно не факт, что она изменитсся в другом.    
2) Это дичайший костыль - делать Thread.sleep(1000) в главном потоке. Никогда так не делайте, если не хотите работать на зарплату среднестатистического индуса.

Comment: И, к тому же, вы говорите, что ваш асинктаск хранится в другом файле, тогда как вы передаете между ними ResGet?

Comment: 1."дичайший костыль" - согласен. 
Просто попробовал все вместе пока сделать. 
2.Идея хорошая: myActivity.taskFinished(results); - а как в MyActivity взять этот result?

Comment: в Activity создаете метод, который принимает ваш result, и вызываете его. Я же написал уже.